How to measure the voltage drop of the power supply when a large load (20 amps) is briefly connected for 20 milliseconds (one cycle of the waveform)
I want to measure the peak voltage of 240V AC supply line accurate to (±5%) within one cycle of the supply waveform, i.e. 20 milliseconds. What should be min. sampling rate and the ADC resolution (12 / 16 bit).

Accurate, by definition, means traceable to standards. And so the first question I have is to have you define the required accuracy and the standards organization to which it must be traced. (NIST? DIN? BSI? etc.) Separately, just the concept of taking a measurement is little easier. Any standard zero-cross SSR will trigger the load when you want it applied (half-cycle.) That's easy enough. And you can cobble up your own so that you get both the active SSR behavior and also a zero-cross signal to trigger an ADC board's sample-gathering. Should work, I think. No product recommendations.

Also, be aware, that traceable to standards means regular calibrations to cope with drift over time. Nothing, and I mean nothing, is stable forever. Things drift. It's a fact of life. So there will be a need for regular (period determined by application and measurement type and other factors) calibration steps to stay within some defined meaning of accurate. Unfortunately, far too many conflate accurate with precise or with trueness. Words matter here. So let us know what you want. Use English here very carefully.

Thanks. I am new to and learning about ADCs. To capture with 5% accuracy what should be the sampling rate and if a 12 or 16 bit ADC can be used - is what I am looking for.

If you mean accuracy then this gets into a whole kettle of fish. Even 5% accuracy can be a fail using standard parts. Some manufacturers of parts will specify an initial accuracy specification. But not all manufacturers do so. So every single part in the circuit matters in working out what you can expect in terms of accuracy. And initial accuracy doesn't tell you anything about what you will get with a part months or years after its manufacturing date. You will want a sample rate of 250 ns for 5%. 12 bit is fine.

If you want to understand the calculation then observe this.

Thanks @periblepsis for the calculation. I totally agree about what "accuracy" really is.

I fixed up my answer. Arsenal needed to kick me in the head to get it right!

Assuming you have some method for accuracy -- and I can't vouch for any of that per comments above -- then as far as the ADC itself I can suggest two things:

12 bit is sufficient. Usually, this means a realizable 10 bits. But that far exceeds your needs of 5%. So it is sufficient to say that a 12-bit ADC is more than enough.
ADC rate should be about \$1\:\text{kHz}\$.

The worst possible case would be where you sample exactly on either side of the peak, with a sample time of \$x\$:

Any other sampling positions would place one or the other of the two bracketing samples closer to the peak value.
The above is the picture. Below is the computation:
w = 2*pi*50                          ' 2 pi f
V = V0*sin(w*t)                      ' some arbitrary sine
tpk = solve( Eq( V, V0 ), t )[0]     ' time of first peak
solve( Eq( V.subs(t,tpk) - V.subs(t,tpk-0.5*x), 0.05*V0 ), x )[0]
0.00202165248208520

So your sampling time should be less than that: \$\le 2 \:\text{ms}\$. But I'd go with half that much, or use \$1\:\text{kHz}\$ to feel secure.
You still need to deal with accuracy. But this gets at the idea of sample rate.

Thank you @periblepsis for the quick explanation.

@JitendraMahapatra Best wishes. And hopefully I didn't make mistakes in writing to you.

I don't get that calculation. For a 240 V AC supply, I get a maximum rate of change at the zero crossing of 107 kV/s. With that you'd get a maximum sample time (not rate) of 160 µs before you run out of the 5 % margin. But at the zero crossing there won't be the peak, so the timing is even more relaxed.

@Arsenal Thanks. Yeah. I'm an idiot. I was looking at % in a general form and that's completely not even the right question. I've corrected the answer. Thanks so much for the kick in the head!
